# re-order file based on multiple columns from different file

Tags: regex, sorting, awk, sed, grep

I have sorted file that looks like this, delimited by spaces:

```
10  1330544 1330555 12.5    2.5 10  0
10  1545844 1545855 6.97674418604651    0   2.32558139534884    4.65116279069767
10  2960444 2960455 14.2857142857143    0   14.2857142857143    0
10  3882344 3882355 14.5038167938931    2.29007633587786    8.3969465648855 3.81679389312977
10  5157844 5157855 10.6666666666667    2.66666666666667    4   4
```

However, this is not an order I want. The order is determined by different file that looks like this, delimited by tabs:

```
17  32972444    32972455    12  0.431   0.31    0.559   0.187   0.591   2.286   0.37    0.426   0.546   1.855   0.846   1.936
9   104333344   104333355   12  0.677   0.51    0.316   1.263   0.735   1.087   1.091   0.739   3.92    4.09    NA  NA
20  31921144    31921155    12  0.155   0.632   0.361   0.466   0.625   0.607   3.091   0.721   1.622   0.127   0.537   1.182
4   8370144 8370155 12  0.525   1.094   1.116   0.63    1.753   0.428   1.346   0.857   0.492   0.843   0.946   1.044
9   21324944    21324955    12  1.493   1.505   0.864   0.64    0.777   0.494   1.173   1.666   2.243   1.377   1.194   1.43
```

Both files can be matched by **first three columns** and both files contain equal number of lines - each tuple from first three columns in second file can be found as tuple made from first three columns in the first file and vice versa.

When I manually search for first row of second file "17 32972444    32972455" I found hit on line 355:

```
17  32972444    32972455    15.7894736842105    0   5.26315789473684    10.5263157894737
```

When I search for second row "9 104333344   104333355", I find hit on row 1196 in first file:

```
9   104333344   104333355   9.21052631578947    1.31578947368421    5.26315789473684    2.63157894736842
```

Therefore, I was thinking of using grep, something like:

```
while read line; do 
echo $line; tosearch=`echo $line | sed 's/ /\t/g'`; 
echo ${tosearch}; grep -P ${tosearch} file1; 
done <file2.columns1-3
```

This doesn't work because I neither know how to grep strings with tabs nor how to substitute them with sed. I do not mind completely different solution to my problem if this idea seems wrong.

Comment: sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines. grep is to find a regexp and print the result. shell is to manipulate files and process. You're not just doing any of those things but you are manipulating text so the tool you should be looking at using is awk. Please [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and the expected output given that input so we can help you.

Comment: Can egrep be used, grep -E?

Comment: @EdMorton I think he is looking for literal strings, which grep can efficiently be used for, too. OP, some examples of input and expected output would be nice, Ed is right there.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line; do echo $line | grep -o  "^\([^ ]* *\)\{3\}"| grep -f- file1; done < rex.txt
```

- rext.txt is the file defining the order,
  everything after first three columns is ignored by grep magic, sed magic not needed
- read replaces tabulator by space anyway
- a column is anything but space, followed by space `[^ ]* *`
- use first grep to only (`-o`) see first (`^`) three (`\{3\}`) columns
- use second grep to look for things fed in via stdin `-f-`

PS: Thanks for teaching me the `read` thing.